# Collection element of type 'double' is not an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

The `inY` property gives an error. What is the correct syntax?

```
UIButton *optionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
NSObject* anim = @{@"target": target, @"inY": infoView.frame.size.height-100, @"outY": @800};
```

Tried creating a variable with it as done with `optionButton` but it doesn't seem to work. I presume I need to cast it as something the collection can understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`infoView.frame.size.height-100` is a float. You can't cast it, you need to box it in an `NSNumber` (similar to what you've done with the `800` value for `outY`):

```
@(infoView.frame.size.height-100)
```

Comment: Thanks! was trying with {} but () was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:xxx]`

This will then create an Objective-C `NSNumber` object which contains the double.

Comment: `@(xxx)` does exactly the same, and is more modern, concise and readable.

Comment: @() @[] @{} @## is the recommended literal syntax that you should use